# Wildcard for aws event bus

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, resources, aws-event-bridge

How can i define resource in event bridge if the folder has subfolders.
Mainfolder/subfolder1/targetfile
Mainfolder/subfolder2/targetfile

So for both the case I want event bridge to trigger. The subfolder1 and subfolder2 are variable as they are date folder.

Comment: is this folders in s3?